# XtraGrid: Change DetailButton style

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid

How to change Grid's Detail button color and style? Highlighted in image below.

[image]

[How to paint the master row's expand buttons within the CustomDrawCell event in exactly the same manner as the XtraGrid does](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2868). This is not working.

Can we add our own button/image? Or is there any option that we can add another button aside with this Detail Button?

**EDIT 1:**
Here is the code.

```
Private Sub GridView1_CustomDrawCell(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs) Handles GridView1.CustomDrawCell

    Dim cell As GridCellInfo = CType(e.Cell, GridCellInfo)

    Dim view As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)

    Dim p As ObjectPainter = cell.RowInfo.ViewInfo.Painter.ElementsPainter.DetailButton

    If Not cell.CellButtonRect.IsEmpty Then

        ObjectPainter.DrawObject(e.Cache, p, _

            New DevExpress.XtraGrid.Drawing.DetailButtonObjectInfoArgs( _

                cell.CellButtonRect, view.GetMasterRowExpanded(cell.RowHandle), cell.RowInfo.IsMasterRowEmpty))

    End If

    ...

    e.Handled = True

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you wish it to look?

Comment: I have custom images that I want to show instead of traditional details button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GridView.CustomDrawCell`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic) event. Just set the `GridCellInfo.CellButtonRect` property to `Rectangle.Empty`, perform the default draw of cell by using `e.DefaultDraw()` method, restore the value of `GridCellInfo.CellButtonRect` property and draw your image after.
Here is example:

```
Private Sub gridView1_CustomDrawCell(sender As Object, e As RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs) Handles gridView1.CustomDrawCell

    Dim info = CType(e.Cell, GridCellInfo)

    If Not info.CellButtonRect.IsEmpty Then
        Dim detailRect = info.CellButtonRect

        info.CellButtonRect = Rectangle.Empty

        e.DefaultDraw()

        info.CellButtonRect = detailRect

        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(yourImageHere, detailRect.X, detailRect.Y)

        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Its working. Can we add another graphic icon? I mean, with default plus/minus button, add another image. Without RepositoryItem.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher You can draw another image like this: `e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(yourAnotherImageHere, detailRect.X + 16, detailRect.Y)`.